# Не стабильно определяется местополежение

Tags: android, gps

Всем привет
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с получением местоположения для запроса погоды.
У меня получается, что в большинстве случаев `LocationManager` возвращает `null`.
Либо геолокация постоянно включена, либо приложение сильно нагружает систему и расходует батарею.

Метод `getLocation` в 90% случаев возвращает `null`, иногда правильные координаты
Метод `getCoordinates` возвращает дефолтные координаты, не смотря на то, что в лог из метода `onLocationChanged` выводятся обновленные данные.

Суть вопроса: просто получить единовременно координаты по запросу пользователя и сразу отключить запрос геолокации.

Вот корень зла

```
public class Locator
{
    private static final int UPD_PERIOD = 1000 * 3600;
    private static final String TAG = Locator.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private double mAltitude;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private Location location;
    private Location defaultLocation;
    private Context context;

    public Locator(Context context)
    {
        mAltitude = 0d;
        mLatitude = 0d;
        this.context = context;
        defaultLocation = new Location(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        defaultLocation.setLongitude(-118.21d);
        defaultLocation.setLatitude(34.03d);
        mLatitude = 34.03d;
        mLongitude = -118.21d;
        locationListener = new LocationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                mAltitude = location.getAltitude();
                mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) { Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged"); }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) { Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled"); }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled"); }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, UPD_PERIOD, 0,
                    locationListener);
        }
        catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("__security_exception__", se.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation() throws SecurityException
    {
        /*
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
                    locationListener);
        */
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return location;
    }

    public double[] getCoordinates()
    {
        return new double[] { mLatitude, mLongitude };
    }
}
```

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() использует локацию которая было получена другими приложениями. Если другие приложения ее не определяли то возвращается null. Из ответа на такой же вопрос  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне получить локацию? Ведь метода getCurrentLocation нет...

Comment: Там написаны 2 варианта. 1 ответ проверяете по всем провайдерам или 2 ответ создаете процедуру которая отслеживает текущую локацию через getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);. Еще есть руководство для разработчиков по получению геолокации https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: От себя скажу что по моему мнению gps запуск занимает несколько минут и если вам нужно определять локацию чаще чем раз в несколько минут, то тут вариант только отслеживать постоянно. С другой стороны если реже то нужно довольно долго ждать чтобы ее получить.

Comment: Ну тут без вариантов. Придется ждать, какое-то уведомление выводить. А как насчет отключения получения данных о местоположении? Надо вызывать `removeLocationUpdates`, но вот как его вызвать? Как только `Location` будет не `null`?..